# Java code written but no expected output after running

Tags: java

This is a programming assignment I am working on. It takes a single string input that represents a sequence of transactions and prints total gain/loss in the end.

I have my code written and *think* it should do what I want...but doesn't. I don't get any kind of output after running the program with the specified input.

The input I'm using is:

> buy 100 share(s) at $20 each;buy 20 share(s) at $24 each;buy 200
>   share(s) at $36 each;sell 150 share(s) at $30 each;buy 50 share(s) at
>   $25 each;sell 200 share(s) at $35 each;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Stocks {

private int shares;
private int price;
private int temp;
private static int total;
private int finalPrice;
private int finalShares;
private Queue<Stocks> StockList = new LinkedList<Stocks>();

private static NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public Stocks()
{
    shares      = 0;
    price       = 0;

}

public Stocks(int shares, int price)
{
    this.shares     = shares;
    this.price      = price;
}

public int getShares()
{
    return this.shares;
}

public int getPrice()
{
    return this.price;
}

public void setShares(int shares)
{
    this.shares = shares;
}

public void setPrice(int price)
{
    this.price = price;
}

public void sell() {
    int sharesToSell = this.getShares();
    int priceToSell = this.getPrice();

    while (!StockList.isEmpty()) {

         int numShares = StockList.peek().getShares();
         int sharePrice = StockList.peek().getPrice();

        if (numShares < sharesToSell || numShares == sharesToSell) {
            temp = sharesToSell - numShares; // remaining shares to sell
            finalShares = sharesToSell - temp; // # shares selling at price
            finalPrice = priceToSell - sharePrice; // shares sold at adjusted price
            total += (finalPrice * finalShares); // Calculates total price
            StockList.remove();
            sharesToSell = temp; // Remaining shares needed to be sold @ price
        }

        if (numShares > sharesToSell) {
            temp = numShares - sharesToSell; // Remaining shares that were bought
            finalPrice = priceToSell - sharePrice; // Shares sold at adjusted price
            total += (finalPrice * sharesToSell); // adds to running total
            StockList.peek().setShares(temp);
        }
    }
}

public void buy() { 
    int numShares = this.getShares();
    int priceToBuy = this.getPrice();

    Stocks newStock = new Stocks(numShares,priceToBuy);
    StockList.add(newStock); // adds stock to list

    int temptotal = (numShares * priceToBuy); // decreases running total
    total += (-1 * temptotal);
}

public static int getTotal() { // gets total profit (or loss)
    return total;
}

// *****MAIN METHOD*****
public static void main(String[] args){


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter transaction sequence:");

    String input = scan.nextLine().trim();
    String[] inputArray = new String[50];
    String[] inputArray2 = new String[50];
    int numShares, sharePrice;

    inputArray = input.split(";");

    for (String i : inputArray) {
        if (i.toUpperCase().contains("BUY")) {
            inputArray2 = i.split(" ");
            inputArray2[4] = inputArray2[4].substring(1);

            try {
                numShares = Integer.parseInt(inputArray2[1]);
                sharePrice = Integer.parseInt(inputArray2[4]);

                Stocks newStock = new Stocks(numShares,sharePrice);
                newStock.buy();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                return;
            }

        }

        else if (i.toUpperCase().contains("SELL")) {
            inputArray2 = input.split(" ");
            inputArray2[4] = inputArray2[4].substring(1);

            try {
                numShares = Integer.parseInt(inputArray2[1]);
                sharePrice = Integer.parseInt(inputArray2[4]);

                Stocks newStock = new Stocks(numShares,sharePrice);
                newStock.sell();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error - input does not contain buy/sell");
        }
    } System.out.println(nf.format(getTotal()));
}
```

}

Comment: Please add homework tag.

Comment: Could you please specify at which line it takes an input?

Comment: Do you have any intuition as to where you think things are going wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to do the ` System.out.println(getTotal());` inside the SELL code? I would think you'd want to do this at the very end.

Comment: @alf Input at scan.nextLine in main method.

Comment: @KurtisNusbaum - I edited the code and now I am stuck at the wrong output. I get a total of $10,930 which is the sum of all stocks bought . I'm assuming something is wrong with my method sell()...

Answer (score 2):

You can clean up your parsing a lot by taking a look at java.util.regex.Matcher and java.util.regex.Pattern.  They will let you match input against regular expressions.  In addition, you can place parens in the regex to extract certain parts.  So in your example, you really only care about three things: the operation(buy or sell), the quantity, and the price.

Here's a small example

```
 String sentence = "john programs 10 times a day";

 // here's our regex - each set of parens is a "group"
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+) programs ([0-9]+) times a day");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);

 String person = matcher.group(1); // here we get the first group
 String number = Integers.parseInt(matcher.group(2)); // here we get the second group

 System.out.println("Person: " + person + " Number: " + number);
```

Comment: I will have to try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the **main** method is returning immediately when it parses a BUY transaction. You probably intended to put the **return** statement inside the **catch** block.